# Exception("storageLevel must be of type pyspark.StorageLevel")

Tags: pyspark, flume

Hi I am trying to do a flume with pyspark integration but getting the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8bjj.png)

This is the code

```
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.flume import FlumeUtils
import sys
from operator import add
from pyspark.sql import functions
hostname= sys.argv[1]
port= sys.argv[2]
renga = SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-client").setAppName("karthik")
amma= SparkContext(conf=renga)
appa=StreamingContext(amma,30)
rajagopal= FlumeUtils.createPollingStream(appa,hostname,port)
rajagopal.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
mohan= rajagopal.map(lambda m:m[1])
kowsi= mohan.flatMap(lambda fm : fm.split(" ")[6] == "deparment")
ujesh= kowsi.map(lambda m : (m.split(" ")[6].split("/")[1],1))
balaji=ujesh.reduceByKey(add)

balaji.saveAsTextFiles("xxxxx/user/shashankbh/jarvis/data/flume/conf")

appa.start()
appa.awaitTermination()
```

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Renganathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function signature of `FlumeUtils.createPollingStream` is

```py
FlumeUtils.createPollingStream(
  ssc,
  addresses,
  storageLevel=StorageLevel(True, True, False, False, 2), 
  maxBatchSize=1000, 
  parallelism=5,
  bodyDecoder=<function utf8_decoder at 0x7efe1daea488>)
```

That means the third positional argument is the storage level. In your code, you pass `port`, which is a string you get from `sys.argv[2]`, therefore not a valid storage level.

This is what the stacktrace means. Learning how to understand stacktraces is a good skill for any programmer.

Comment: thanks for the comment Oliver and i have a doubt regarding the same i successfully done the previous step but while running in Cluster it throws the Following error.

Comment: Hi Renga, I’m glad I could help. For your follow-up question, please ask a new question and copy the textual description of the error in that question if you need more help.